# indexing groupby object with multiple keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.DataFrame that I want to convert to a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are the values of the first column, and the values of the dictionary are the values from the second and third column put in a tuple or list. I tried to achieve this like so:

```
    df 
    form  name  state
    CCH   bla1  act
    BGH   bla2  act
    BGH   bla3  nad
    KMJ   bla4  nad
    FRT   bla5  nad
```

I want the dict to look like this:

```
    {CCH:[(bla1, act)], BGH:[(bla2,act),(bla3,nad)],KMJ:[(bla4,nad)],FRT:[(bla5,nad)]}
```

My current code to achieve this is this:

```
    df.groupby('form')[['name','state']].apply(tuple).to_dict()
```

But I get this output :

```
    {CCH:('name','state'),BGH:('name','state'),KMJ:('name','state'),FRT:('name','state')}
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, try `apply` tuple along axis 1. Here is one solution using a dict comprehension:

```
d = {k: v[['name', 'state']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
     for k, v in df.groupby('form')}
```

[out]

```
{'BGH': [('bla2', 'act'), ('bla3', 'nad')],
 'CCH': [('bla1', 'act')],
 'FRT': [('bla5', 'nad')],
 'KMJ': [('bla4', 'nad')]}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it help solving your issue